# cocoa's event prior to applicationDidFinishLaunching

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I'm trying to load a window's size and other properties on application start. Unfortunately, if i do it on

```
applicationDidFinishLaunching
```

or

```
applicationWillFinishLaunching
```

... i get an ugly flicker, showing the unmodified window and quickly switching to a modified one. I know how to do this for my non-main windows that run with window controllers (usually i do this in awake from nib event), but how would i do it in an application delegate?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell the window to not be visible at launch, which means you can create your window, mess with its frame size and all that, and *then* show it.

Comment: Simply genious! Why didn't i think of that ... Thanks :)